# To Convert MicrosoftOffice Docs+PDF+Images++Audio/Video into Swf file

Tags: visual-c++, ms-office, document

I want to convert MicrosoftOffice Docs(.doc,.docx,ppt,xlsx,xls) +PDF+Images++Audio/Video into an swf file. The idea behind this project is to open the documents on any machine which have a flash plugin. I want to do this in VC++.

Answer (score 0):

Use http://www.swftools.org/ (Open Source)

Makes SWF from PDF, images, video, sound.

To convert from office formats, you will probably need to first convert office files to PDF, and then PDF to SWF. There are many tools to do this, one of the best is OpenOffice in server mode (no user interface).

An example implementation is Alfresco Share (also Open Source), which uses swftools and OpenOffice to convert all sorts of files to SWF. Alfresco Share calls those external programs from Java, so you can call them from VC++ the same way.

Comment: @Nicolas: Thank you so much for you reply.........one more request.......Can you kindly elaborate please..................How alfresco share can do this for me...............

Comment: Unfortunately, Alfresco Share will not "do this for you" if you are in a VC++ project. It is just an example of how to use SWFTOOLS and OpenOffice server mode to convert many kinds of files to SWF. It stands as a proof that it is possible, but you will probably have to write yourself the VC++ to call SWFTOOLS and OpenOffice server mode.

Comment: FYI, Alfresco uses JODConverter to convert office files to PDF. So you can use JODConverter+SWFTOOLS to reach your goal.